# Plain old C: accessing member of a function returning struct

Tags: c

Please could you help me with a question of "legitimacy".

Assuming that foo() is a function returning a structure, is it officially acceptable to assign a member of the structure directly to a variable, for example

`x = foo().member`

Both the GNU-C complier and an embedded C compiler (Keil) accept this without any grumbles but is this actually legitimate according to the official C standard or is it just a relaxed attitude of these particular compilers? If it's legit, has it always been legit or is it a recent development?

Here's an example that compiles and runs OK:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} footype;

footype testfoo(void)
{
    footype n;

    n.a = 1;
    n.b = 2;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    printf("\nTest = %d\n", testfoo().a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a standard C syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The `testfoo` function returns a temporary instance of the structure. This instance can be used at once as show in the example, and the temporary instance is valid until the full expression (i.e. the `printf` call in your case) is done.

It's equivalent to

```
{
    footype temp = testfoo();
    printf("\nTest = %d\n", temp.a);
}
```

Comment: To be picky, it is equivalent to your example surrounded by `{ }`.

Comment: Isn't it undefined behavior since the struct is on the stack and can be garbage at anytime? I always thought if you need a struct from a function it has to be malloc'd. And if you access only a member without storing a reference, it leaks. Just my 2c

Comment: The struct returned is not necessarily temporary.

Comment: @user687976 You can pass around structures *by value* just like any other values, meaning the structure will be copied (handled by the compiler).

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard case of expression evaluation result.
The flow:

```
testfoo().a
```

is a standard C expression where:

1. `testfoo()` result, what the function returns, is in our case a struct `footype`.
2. Then compiler applies the operator `.` to the this struct.
3. The dot operator access the field `a` and creates a new result.
4. The final expression result is used in the `printf()`.
   This is always valid.
   I.e.:

   `int *bar(void);    //bar is afunnction that returns an int pointer
       ...
       i = bar()[10];    //We access the 10th element pointed by bar()`

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest I compiled your example and looked at the assembly generated. First, every compiler can solve this in its own way. I use VC2008.

In your example, the compiler returned the struct in its registers.

I changed the struct to include a large string, so the compiler would run out of registers. It now changed the signature of the function to receive a pointer, and had allocated an instance of the struct on the stack (caller's stackframe), then called the function with a pointer to this struct. The function copied the result to the struct on the stack using this pointer.